# Android 2.1 - Negative margin doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-layout

Negative margin on Android 2.1 doesn't work properly, because the element with negative margin replace with a white background the space underneath the element. How to solve it?

Comment: I am not really sure if negative margin is really a good approach, but take a look at this statiscs: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Yes I know, I wanna only know for curiosity why it doens't work properly on Android 2.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't work on 2.1, probably it won't work on 2.0-, because negative margin could be added by Google only on android 2.2+ (This is a guess, I never used negative margin, only padding instead).